# Mid function excel is skipping 0's in text from UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim ndc, qty As String


ndc = "'" & TextBox1.Value
qty = TextBox2.Text

ndc = Right(ndc, TextBox1.TextLength - 1)
ndc = Left(ndc, TextBox1.TextLength - 2)
```

Above code is used to validate UPC data which is read in with a "/" in the front and back of a number. Number can be of varying lengths too, here is a sample:

```
\357237031056\
\354838555509\
\001798022021\
```

here is my result:

```
357237031056
354838555509
1798022021
```

So the last entry is where the mess up is, what gives? i formatted it as text using the "'" and I also tried doing .Text as well, still gives the same problem.

Comment: `Dim ndc, qty As String` - here `ndc` is a variant (only `qty` is declared as String). Try declaring `ndc` as String.

Comment: The value is simply converting on-the-fly from text with or without leading zeroes that looks like a number to an actual number. You should also notice a shift from a default left alignment for the text to a default right alignment for true numbers. Do you wish to work with true numbers (with a custom number format that displays the leading zeroes or with text that looks like a number but actually has the leading zeroes?

Comment: If I run your code as-is and `Debug.Print ndc` I get `001798022021`,so what are you then doing with ndc so it ends up without the leading zeros?  As @Jeeped mentions this just looks like automatic number conversion, which will happen if you put that value into a  cell.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore my comment - the outcome of the code below doesn't change if you declare `ndc` as String (though you should do that if that's the type you intend it to hold)

Using the input value of `\001798022021\` -

```
Private Sub Tester()

Dim ndc, qty As String

    ndc = "'" & TextBox1.Value

    ndc = Right(ndc, TextBox1.TextLength - 1)
    ndc = Left(ndc, TextBox1.TextLength - 2)

    Debug.Print ndc         '  001798022021

    Range("A1").Value = ndc '  1798022021

    Range("A2").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A2").Value = ndc '  001798022021

End Sub
```

Comment: awesome, so it seems that excel is converting to number at time of input. used your tip and changed numberformat to "@", which i don't know what that means but it works! So used to java and c coding that vba seems outlandish.